# jQuery Progress Bar (Canvas load time)

Tags: jquery, css, html5-canvas

So I'm using this jQuery plugin:

http://p.ar2oor.pl/cprogress/

I won't post any code cause there is just way to much. Basically, if you go to the site you will see how quickly their progress bar loads. I have set mine up working in the exact same fashion, but just with different images.
It delays for half a second and then appears. Why is it doing it, and what can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Unless you can isolate (or bother) the problem it is very difficult for people to help you. Try jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Yeah sorry I've been looking and looking but I don't understand the code well enough to be able to find the problem. I'll give jsfiddle a go.

Answer (score 0):

Your slider is showing up slower because your image is loading slow.

**Are you pulling the images from a different server?** - Put the images to your server.

**Is your slider visible on page load or it will be shown, after some action?** In that case, preload the image right after document / page load. So when the slider will be shown, the image is already in the browsers cache.

All in all, you are facing optimization problems, and without full code, we cannot help you. As there must be multiple factors, that are slowing down the load.